# How can I mount the same persistent volume on multiple pods?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have a three node GCE cluster and a single-pod GKE deployment with three replicas. I created the PV and PVC like so:

```
# Create a persistent volume for web content
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nginx-content
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
   - ReadOnlyMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
--
# Request a persistent volume for web content
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-content-claim
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
spec:
  accessModes: [ReadOnlyMany]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

They are referenced in the container spec like so:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: launcher.gcr.io/google/nginx1
        name: nginx-container
        volumeMounts:
          - name: nginx-content
            mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-content
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nginx-content-claim
```

Even though I created the volumes as ReadOnlyMany, only one pod can mount the volume at any given time. The rest give "Error 400: RESOURCE_IN_USE_BY_ANOTHER_RESOURCE". How can I make it so all three replicas read the same web content from the same volume?

Answer (score 54):

First I'd like to point out one fundamental discrapency in your configuration. Note that when you use your `PersistentVolumeClaim` defined as in your example, you don't use your `nginx-content` `PersistentVolume` at all. You can easily verify it by running:

```
kubectl get pv
```

on your **GKE cluster**. You'll notice that apart from your manually created `nginx-content` `PV`, there is another one, which was automatically provisioned based on the `PVC` that you applied.

Note that in your `PersistentVolumeClaim` definition you're explicitely referring the `default` storage class which has nothing to do with your manually created `PV`. Actually even if you completely omit the annotation:

```
annotations:
        volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
```

it will work exactly the same way, namely the `default` storage class will be used anyway. Using the default storage class on **GKE** means that **GCE Persistent Disk** will be used as your volume provisioner. You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#storageclasses):

> Volume implementations such as gcePersistentDisk are configured
> through StorageClass resources. GKE creates a default StorageClass for
> you which uses the standard persistent disk type (ext4). The default
> StorageClass is used when a PersistentVolumeClaim doesn't specify a
> StorageClassName. You can replace the provided default StorageClass
> with your own.

But let's move on to the solution of the problem you're facing.

#### Solution:

First, I'd like to emphasize **you don't have to use any NFS-like filesystems to achive your goal**.

If you need your `PersistentVolume` to be available in `ReadOnlyMany` mode, **GCE Persistent Disk** is a perfect solution that entirely meets your requirements.

It can be mounted in `ro` mode by many `Pods` at the same time and what is even more important by many `Pods`, scheduled on different **GKE** `nodes`. Furthermore it's really simple to configure and it works on **GKE** out of the box.

In case you want to use your storage in `ReadWriteMany` mode, I agree that something like NFS may be the only solution as **GCE Persistent Disk** doesn't provide such capability.

Let's take a closer look how we can configure it.

We need to start from defining our `PVC`. This step was actually already done by yourself but you got lost a bit in further steps. Let me explain how it works.

The following configuration is correct (as I mentioned `annotations` section can be omitted):

```
# Request a persistent volume for web content
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-content-claim
spec:
  accessModes: [ReadOnlyMany]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

However I'd like to add one important comment to this. You said:

> Even though I created the volumes as ReadOnlyMany, only one pod can
> mount the volume at any given time.

Well, actually **you didn't**. I know it may seem a bit tricky and somewhat surprising but this is not the way how defining `accessModes` really works. In fact it's a widely misunderstood concept. First of all **you cannot define access modes in `PVC`** in a sense of putting there the constraints you want. Supported **access modes** are inherent feature of a particular storage type. They are already defined by the storage provider.

What you actually do in `PVC` definition is requesting a `PV` that supports the particular access mode or access modes. Note that it's in a form of **a list** which means you may provide many different access modes that you want your `PV` to support.

Basically it's like saying: *"Hey! Storage provider! Give me a volume that supports `ReadOnlyMany` mode."* You're asking this way for a storage that will satisfy your requirements. Keep in mind however that you can be given more than you ask. And this is also our scenario when asking for a `PV` that supports `ReadOnlyMany` mode in **GCP**. It creates for us a `PersistentVolume` which meets our requirements we listed in `accessModes` section but it also supports `ReadWriteOnce` mode. Although we didn't ask for something that also supports `ReadWriteOnce` you will probably agree with me that storage which has a built-in support for those two modes fully satisfies our request for something that supports `ReadOnlyMany`. So basically this is the way it works.

Your `PV` that was automatically provisioned by GCP in response for your `PVC` supports those two `accessModes` and if you don't specify explicitely in `Pod` or `Deployment` definition that you want to mount it in **read-only** mode, by default it is mounted in **read-write** mode.

You can easily verify it by attaching to the `Pod` that was able to successfully mount the `PersistentVolume`:

```
kubectl exec -ti pod-name -- /bin/bash
```

and trying to write something on the mounted filesystem.

The error message you get:

```
"Error 400: RESOURCE_IN_USE_BY_ANOTHER_RESOURCE"
```

concerns specifically **GCE Persistent Disk** that is already mounted by one **GKE** `node` in `ReadWriteOnce` mode and it cannot be mounted by another `node` on which the rest of your `Pods` were scheduled.

If you want it to be mounted in `ReadOnlyMany` mode, you need to specify it explicitely in your `Deployment` definition by adding `readOnly: true` statement in the `volumes` section under `Pod's` template specification like below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: nginx-content
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-content
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nginx-content-claim
          readOnly: true
```

Keep in mind however that to be able to mount it in `readOnly` mode, first we need to pre-populate such volume with data. Otherwise you'll see another error message, saying that unformatted volume cannot be mounted in read only mode.

The easiest way to do it is by creating a single `Pod` which will serve only for copying data which was already uploaded to one of our **GKE nodes** to our destination `PV`.

Note that pre-populating `PersistentVolume` with data can be done in many different ways. You can mount in such `Pod` only your `PersistentVolume` that you will be using in your `Deployment` and get your data using `curl` or `wget` from some external location saving it directly on your destination `PV`. It's up to you.

In my example I'm showing how to do it using additional [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) volume that allows us to mount into our `Pod` a `directory`, `partition` or `disk` (in my example I use a directory `/var/tmp/test` located on one of my GKE nodes) available on one of our kubernetes nodes. It's much more flexible solution than `hostPath` as we don't have to care about scheduling such `Pod` to particular node, that contains the data. Specific **node affinity** rule is already defined in `PersistentVolume` and `Pod` is automatically scheduled on specific node.

To create it we need 3 things:

`StorageClass`:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

`PersistentVolume` definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /var/tmp/test
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - <gke-node-name>
```

and finally `PersistentVolumeClaim`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
```

Then we can create our temporary `Pod` which will serve only for copying data from our **GKE node** to our **GCE Persistent Disk**.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/mnt/source"
        name: mypd
      - mountPath: "/mnt/destination"
        name: nginx-content
  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim
    - name: nginx-content
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: nginx-content-claim
```

Paths you can see above are not really important. The task of this `Pod` is only to allow us to copy our data to the destination `PV`. Eventually our `PV` will be mounted in completely different path.

Once the `Pod` is created and both volumes are successfully mounted, we can attach to it by running:

```
kubectl exec -ti my-pod -- /bin/bash
```

Withing the `Pod` simply run:

```
cp /mnt/source/* /mnt/destination/
```

That's all. Now we can `exit` and delete our temporary `Pod`:

```
kubectl delete pod mypod
```

Once it is gone, we can apply our `Deployment` and our `PersistentVolume` finally can be mounted in `readOnly` mode by all the `Pods` located on various **GKE nodes**:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: nginx-content
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-content
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nginx-content-claim
          readOnly: true
```

Btw. if you are ok with the fact that your `Pods` will be scheduled only on one particular node, you can give up on using **GCE Persistent Disk** at all and switch to the above mentioned [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) volume. This way all your `Pods` will be able not only to read from it but also to write to it at the same time. The only caveat is that all those `Pods` will be running on a single node.

Comment: And this IS a great answer. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to have a PVC w/ access modes `[ReadWriteOnce, ReadOnlyMany]`, one pod mounting it as r/w and others mounting it as r/o?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a NFS like file system. On Google Cloud, Filestore is the right product for this (NFS managed). You have a tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares) for achieving your configuration

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a shared volume claim with ReadWriteMany (RWX) type if you want to share the volume across different nodes and provide highly scalable solution. Like using NFS server.

You can find out how to deploy an NFS server here:

https://www.shebanglabs.io/run-nfs-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/

And then you can mount volumes (directories from NFS server) as follows:

https://www.shebanglabs.io/how-to-set-up-read-write-many-rwx-persistent-volumes-with-nfs-on-kubernetes/

I've used such a way to deliver shared static content between +8 k8s deployments (+200 pods) serving 1 Billion requests a month over Nginx. and it did work perfectly with that NFS setup :)

Answer (score 1):

Google provides NFS like filesystem called as Google Cloud Filestore. You can mount that on multiple pods.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing my deployment strategy from Rolling to Recreate.