# Initializing a dynamically provisioned shared volume with ReadOnlyMany access mode

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes, gce-persistent-disk

My GKE deployment consists of N pods (possibly on different nodes) and a shared volume, which is [dynamically provisioned](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) by `pd.csi.storage.gke.io` and is a Persistent Disk in GCP. I need to initialize this disk with data before the pods go live.

My problem is I need to set `accessModes` to `ReadOnlyMany` and be able to mount it to all pods across different nodes in read-only mode, which I assume effectively would make it impossible to mount it in write mode to the `initContainer`.

Is there a solution to this issue? [Answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754103/how-to-pre-populate-a-readonlymany-persistent-volume) suggests a good solution for a case when each pod has their own disk mounted, but I need to have one disk shared among all pods since my data is quite large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GKE 1.21 and later, you can enable the [managed Filestore CSI driver](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/filestore-csi-driver) in your clusters.  You can enable the driver for new clusters

```
gcloud container clusters create CLUSTER_NAME \
    --addons=GcpFilestoreCsiDriver ...
```

or update existing clusters:

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME \
   --update-addons=GcpFilestoreCsiDriver=ENABLED
```

Once you've done that, create a storage class (or have or platform admin do it):

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: filestore-example
provisioner: filestore.csi.storage.gke.io
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  tier: standard
  network: default
```

After that, you can use PVCs and dynamic provisioning:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: podpvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: filestore-example
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Ti
```

Answer (score 1):

`...I need to have one disk shared among all pods`

You can try Filestore. First your create a FileStore [instance](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/creating-instances) and save your data on a FileStore volume. Then you [install](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/filestore-csi-driver#enabling_the_on_a_new_cluster) FileStore driver on your cluster. Finally you share the data with pods that needs to read the data using a PersistentVolume [referring](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gcp-filestore-csi-driver/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/pre-provision/preprov-pv.yaml) the FileStore instance and volume above.

Comment: Looks like a great solution, however, I have a company limitation which does not allow me to use `PersistentVolume`s. I can only use `PersistentVolumeClaim`s and dynamic provisioning